# getElementById.innerHTML with if else condition

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, business-catalyst

I have coded this in Business Catalyst website.

```
<li class="instock"><span id="stock">Stock</span><span id="stockcount" style="display: none;">{tag_instock}</span> </li>

<script>
var stockcnt = document.getElementById('stockcount').innerHTML;
if (stockcnt==0){
 document.getElementById('stock').InnerHTML="Out of Stock";
}else{
document.getElementById('stock').InnerHTML="In Stock";
}
</script>
```

What i want to do is if `stockcount` == 0 change the innerHTML of `stock`

{tag_instock} will automatically generate number according to the stock count when page loads.

when i tried this code. it didn't work. can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive, its `innerHTML` (lose the capital "I")

```
document.getElementById('stock').innerHTML="In Stock";
```

Comment: Ah.. Thanks. i don't know how did i miss it.